# Error in hexo deploy to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, hexo

I am trying to do a hexo deploy to heroku, but this error shows up:

```
    remote: Building source:        
remote: 
remote: -----> Failed to detect set buildpack https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/nodejs.tgz        
remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure        
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed        
remote: Verifying deploy...        
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to pure-caverns-85771.        
remote: 
To git@heroku.com:pure-caverns-85771.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:pure-caverns-85771.git'
```

I do have the `package.json` and I have install hexo-deployer-heroku pluggin.. any ideas?

Comment: Try setting buildpack first: `heroku buildpacks:set https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/nodejs.tgz` or `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs`

Comment: Thanks, it is already set on the app.

Comment: I mean.. it was already set..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [removing the already set buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-modifications), so Heroku will automatically set one for you.

Also make sure your `package.json` is being pushed to Heroku.